# Error TS2554 in *.directive.spec.ts

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-directive

I am running "ng test" for the first time and get this error:

ERROR in src/app/_directives/head-title.directive.spec.ts(5,23): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.

Since the spec.ts files is autogenerated by Angular, I have no idea what to do...

This is my directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
  selector: '[edHeadTitle]'
})

export class HeadTitleDirective implements AfterContentInit{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private titleService: Title) {}

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.titleService.setTitle(this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }

}
```

And this is the corresponding spec.ts:

```
import { HeadTitleDirective } from './head-title.directive';

describe('HeadTitleDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new HeadTitleDirective();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Apparently the offending part is "new HeadTitleDirective()" ... I guess there should be some parameters, but which and how?

Version info from package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is basic coding.

Here is your class signature :

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef,private titleService: Title) {}
```

Here is how you create it :

```
const directive = new HeadTitleDirective();
```

Do yo usee the issue there ?

To resolve it, simply create mocks of your dependencies.

```
let elRefMock = {
  nativeElement: document.createElement('div')
};

let serviceMock = {
  setTitle: (title: string) => null
};

const directive = new HeadTitleDirective(elRefMock, serviceMock);
```

Comment: Yes... I see the issue. I need to add som arguments. But I have no idea what to write... I am fairly new to Angular 6 and I never edited any spec file before, since they are autogenerated...

Comment: They are generated for your convenience, if you don't edit them they're as useful as if they were not existing. I updated my answer with a piece of code to resolve your issue, but consider reading the guide about testing in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks :-) ... one issue though... The serviceMock is somehow invalid. I am getting: Argument of type '{setTitle: (title:string) => any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Title'. Property '_doc' is missing in type '{setTitle: (title: string) => any;}'.

Comment: `new HeadTitleDirective(elRefMock; serviceMock as Title)` should correct your issue. Are you starting in Typescript ?

Comment: Nice... much better. Also the semicolon after elRefMock must be a comma... at least that is what Visual Studio Code tells me.
Thanks a million. I see I have a lot of reading to do. Going from AngularJS 1.x to Angular 6.x has been quite a journey. And yes, Typescript is also new to me. But things are lightening up. My project is using simpel animation, ngx-translate with xliffmerge, api communication and so on... It's been very interesting so far :-D

Comment: Yeah, going from AJS to Angular is juste pure pleasure. I would suggest you read the [documentation of Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html) to find very useful things such as casting your variables and such. This is how you'll get the most experience out of it !

Comment: Great!! I'll do that :-D

Answer (score 5):

I also dont fully understand why this error happens, but it works by setting the directive type directly to directive const in your specs.ts

```js
import { HeadTitleDirective } from './head-title.directive';

describe('HeadTitleDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = HeadTitleDirective;
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```